Implement Spring Boot Service based on yml file configs
I have the following test Java code into Spring Boot microservice:
https://github.com/rcbandit111/profile-protection/blob/main/src/main/java/com/profile/protection/admin/service/impl/KeysServiceImpl.java#L27
I need to process the API request based on the yml configuration:
Example:
profile-protection:
  dataClasses:
    - name: USER_INFO
      activeVersionName: version-1
      versions:
        - versionName: version-1
          algorithm: AES
          encryptKeyName: user
    - name: SAMPLE_ENCRYPTION
      activeVersionName: version-1
      versions:
        - versionName: version-1
          algorithmName: AES
          encryptKeyName: user_aes

The solution that I can think of is to create a Factory model which selects implementation services based on key value:
@Component
public class EncryptionServiceFactory {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final EncryptionServiceProperties encryptionServiceProperties;

    @Autowired
    public EncryptionServiceFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext, EncryptionServiceProperties encryptionServiceProperties) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.encryptionServiceProperties = encryptionServiceProperties;
    }

    public EncryptionService getService(String dataClassName) {
        return (EncryptionService) applicationContext.getBean(dataClassName);
    }
}

.....

// Implementation:

public interface EncryptionService {
    String encrypt(String plaintext);
    String decrypt(String ciphertext);
}

@Service("USER_INFO")
public class UserInfoEncryptionService implements EncryptionService {

    // This would use configuration values for encryption
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        // Implement AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption logic here
        return "encrypted-" + plaintext;
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String ciphertext) {
        // Implement AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding decryption logic here
        return "decrypted-" + ciphertext;
    }
}

.....

@Service("SAMPLE_ENCRYPTION")
public class SampleEncryptionService implements EncryptionService {

    // This would use configuration values for encryption
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        // Implement AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption logic here
        return "encrypted-" + plaintext;
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String ciphertext) {
        // Implement AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding decryption logic here
        return "decrypted-" + ciphertext;
    }
}

.....

@RestController
@RequestMapping("..........")
public class EncryptionController {

    private final EncryptionServiceFactory encryptionServiceFactory;

    @Autowired
    public EncryptionController(EncryptionServiceFactory encryptionServiceFactory) {
        this.encryptionServiceFactory = encryptionServiceFactory;
    }

    @PostMapping("/{dataClassName}/encrypt")
    public String encrypt(@PathVariable String dataClassName, @RequestBody String plaintext) {
        EncryptionService encryptionService = encryptionServiceFactory.getService(dataClassName);
        return encryptionService.encrypt(plaintext);
    }

}

As you can see based on the dataClass value service is selected. But the issue is that I have a fixed Spring Boot Services. IF I need to add more types of dataClasses into yml config file I need aslo to add Sprign Boot Services.
Is it possible to design the  code in a such a way that I can add more dataClass names with sub configuration values without adding new Java code?

As I can see you don't need to create implementations for each data type, you could just create one implementation that uses the properties from your yaml file. While your applicatiom starts, you need to read your yaml, then create a keys service for each data type and register them somewhere, so that you can access them by data type anywhere.
First of all, create a configuration properties for your yaml props:
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "profile-protection")
@Data
public class ProfileProtectionProperties {

    private List<DataClass> dataClasses;

    @Data
    public static class DataClass {

        private String name;
        private String activeVersionName;
        private List<Version> versions;

        @Data
        public static class Version {

            private String versionName;
            private String algorithmName;
            private String encryptAlgorithmName;
            private String encryptKeyName;
            private int encryptKeyVersion;
        }

        public Version getActualVersion() {
            return this.versions.stream()
                    .filter(version -> version.getVersionName().equals(this.activeVersionName))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No active version found"));
        }
    }
}

Then I would create a DefaultKeysService like this:
public class DefaultKeysService implements KeysService {

    private final ProfileProtectionProperties.DataClass             dataClass;
    private final ProfileProtectionProperties.DataClass.Version     actualVersion;

    public DefaultKeysService(ProfileProtectionProperties.DataClass dataClass) {
        this.dataClass = dataClass;
        this.actualVersion = dataClass.getActualVersion();
    }

    public String forDataType() {
        return this.dataClass.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String encryptValueRequest(EncryptValueRequest encryptValueRequest) {
        // todo
        // write your code here using your properties

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void decryptValueRequest(DecryptValueRequest decryptValueRequest) {
        // todo
        // write your code here using your properties
    }
}

Then create a registry to store keys services along with their data types.
@Component
public class KeysServiceRegistry {

    private final Map<String, KeysService> keysServices = new HashMap<>();

    public void register(String forDataType, KeysService keysService) {
        if (keysServices.containsKey(forDataType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keys service already registered for " + forDataType);
        }

        keysServices.put(forDataType, keysService);
    }

    // later you'll use this method to get the desired service for given data type
    public KeysService provide(String forDataType) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(keysServices.get(forDataType))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Keys service not found for " + forDataType));
    }
}

And also the registrar bean, that will read the properties before the application starts, create a service for each data class and register them along with their data types:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KeysServiceRegistrar {

    private final KeysServiceRegistry           keysServiceRegistry;
    private final ProfileProtectionProperties   protectionProperties;

    // read all the properties before the application starts, create a service for each data class, register all of them by data type
    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void register() {
        protectionProperties.getDataClasses()
                .stream()
                .map(dataClass -> {
                    // create a service for each data class
                    DefaultKeysService defaultKeysService = new DefaultKeysService(dataClass);
                    return defaultKeysService;
                })
                .forEach(defaultKeysService ->
                        keysServiceRegistry.register(defaultKeysService.forDataType(), defaultKeysService));

    }
}

Having this design you only will need to add a new properties into your yaml if you get some new data type.
So your controller would look like this:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile-protection", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class EncryptionController {

    private final KeysServiceRegistry keysServiceRegistry;

    @PostMapping("/{dataClassName}/encrypt")
    public String encrypt(@PathVariable String dataClassName, @RequestBody String plaintext) {
        EncryptionService encryptionService = keysServiceRegistry.provide(dataClassName);
        return encryptionService.encrypt(plaintext);
    }
}


Thanks, I have added the code into the test project. Please see the link to the Github project above. But when I start the project I get error: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.profile.protection.admin.service.DefaultKeysService required a bean of type 'com.profile.protection.admin.service.ProfileProtectionProperties$DataClass' that could not be found.  Please push a PR with a fix if you prefer.

@PeterPenzov remove '@Service' annotation from DefaultKeysService. You have copied my code incorrectly.

I did it but now I get error: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.profile.protection.admin.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.profile.protection.admin.service.KeysService' that could not be found. 

@PeterPenzov again.. could you just at least copy my code correctly? Compare my user controller and yours. And it also would be better if you’d got the idea of my code.

@PeterPenzov so, that solution is what you wanted to achieve?

Sorry for the delay. I made the changes but again I get issue. Can I ask you to make a PR into the repository project with proper changes, please? I can't find what I'm missing.

@PeterPenzov please... at least copy and paste the code correctly... delete your UserController and use my EncryptionController...

Ok, I made the changes carefully. I can start the app. Thanks! One more question. Is it possible to simplify the entire solution? For example remove @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)?
